# How to create a DataFrame with the columns and fields in a file?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to create an DataFrame with a header and the fields.
The header and fields are in a file. The file is specified as below. 
The schema is in the field5, col1,col2... is my schema and the values comes after field6.

```
field1 value1;
field2 value2;
field3 value3;
field4 value4;
field5 17 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8;
field6
val1 val 2 val3 val4 val5 val6 val7 val8
val9 val10 val11 val12 val13 val14 val15 val16
val17 val18 val19 val20 val21 val22 val23 val24;
EndOfFile;
```

Above is the file, and I want to extract the values col1,col2.......col8 and create a Struct out of it and create a dataframe with the values which comes after field6.

Should I extract field5 with normal Java code ? Is it possible to do in Spark Java ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the following (but I'm using Scala so converting it to Java is your home exercise):

1. Load the file as a regular (almost unstructured) text file using `spark.read.text`
2. Filter out the irrelevant lines
3. Create another DataFrame with the requested schema and rows

Let's see the Scala code:

```
val input = spark.read.text("input.txt")
scala> input.show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------+
|value                                             |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|field1 value1;                                    |
|field2 value2;                                    |
|field3 value3;                                    |
|field4 value4;                                    |
|field5 17 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8;|
|field6                                            |
|val1 val 2 val3 val4 val5 val6 val7 val8          |
|val9 val10 val11 val12 val13 val14 val15 val16    |
|val17 val18 val19 val20 val21 val22 val23 val24;  |
|EndOfFile;                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------+

// trying to impress future readers ;-)
val unnecessaryLines = (2 to 4).
  map(n => 'value startsWith s"field$n").
  foldLeft('value startsWith "field1") { case (f, orfield) => f or orfield }.
  or('value startsWith "field6").
  or('value startsWith "EndOfFile")
scala> unnecessaryLines.explain(true)
((((StartsWith('value, field1) || StartsWith('value, field2)) || StartsWith('value, field3)) || StartsWith('value, field4)) || StartsWith('value, EndOfFile))

// Filter out the irrelevant lines
val onlyRelevantLines = input.filter(!unnecessaryLines)
scala> onlyRelevantLines.show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------+
|value                                             |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|field5 17 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8;|
|val1 val 2 val3 val4 val5 val6 val7 val8          |
|val9 val10 val11 val12 val13 val14 val15 val16    |
|val17 val18 val19 val20 val21 val22 val23 val24;  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

With that we got the only relevant lines from the file. *Time for some fun!*

```
// Remove field5 from the first line only and `;` at the end
val field5 = onlyRelevantLines.head.getString(0) // we're leaving Spark space and enter Scala
// the following is pure Scala code (no Spark whatsoever)
val header = field5.substring("field5 17 ".size).dropRight(1).split("\\s+").toSeq

val rows = onlyRelevantLines.filter(!('value startsWith "field5"))
scala> :type rows
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
scala> rows.show(false)
+------------------------------------------------+
|value                                           |
+------------------------------------------------+
|val1 val 2 val3 val4 val5 val6 val7 val8        |
|val9 val10 val11 val12 val13 val14 val15 val16  |
|val17 val18 val19 val20 val21 val22 val23 val24;|
+------------------------------------------------+
```

With that, you have a `Dataset` of lines that should be split (per space). In unreleased Spark 2.2.0, there is going to be a method [csv](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L440) that would load the dataset and given separator would give us what we want:

```
def csv(csvDataset: Dataset[String]): DataFrame
```

That's not available yet so we have to do something similar.

Let's try to stick to Spark SQL's Dataset API as long as we can.

```
val words = rows.select(split($"value", "\\s+") as "words")
scala> words.show(false)
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|words                                                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|[val1, val, 2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8]       |
|[val9, val10, val11, val12, val13, val14, val15, val16]  |
|[val17, val18, val19, val20, val21, val22, val23, val24;]|
+---------------------------------------------------------+

// The following is just a series of withColumn's for every column in header

val finalDF = header.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(words) { case (df, (hdr, idx)) =>
  df.withColumn(hdr, $"words".getItem(idx)) }.
  drop("words")
scala> finalDF.show
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| col1| col2| col3| col4| col5| col6| col7|  col8|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| val1|  val|    2| val3| val4| val5| val6|  val7|
| val9|val10|val11|val12|val13|val14|val15| val16|
|val17|val18|val19|val20|val21|val22|val23|val24;|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

Done!